# Starting JBoss 7.1.1 from eclipse fails

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, jboss7.x, jboss-tools

When starting JBoss from the servers view inside Eclipse Indigo SR2 with JBoss Tools 2.3.0 on my machine, everything runs fine.

I have copied all contents of my work folder containing Eclipse and JBoss-7.1.1.Final to a different machine.

Now, when I try to start the server, it fails with this message:

> Starting JBoss 7.1.1 Runtime encountered an error. The archive: /jboss/jboss-modules.jar which is referenced by the classpath, does not exist.

I don't see anything referencing the jar in the runtime or server or project configurations. And the `jboss-modules.jar` is inside the root folder of the JBoss server, as expected. There are no deployments in the `standalone.xml`.
Both machines are running SuSe 12. `.bashrc` and `.profile` are empty.

The server starts fine from command line.

I have created a new runtime and a server using this runtime from scratch in Eclipse, but get the same error.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution just now:

1. I have found the reference to the jboss-modules.jar in the launch configuration of the server under `User Libraries`. All attempts to delete it failed. After removing or resetting to defaults and applying, I started the server, received the same error and the .jar was in the launch cofig classpath again.
2. I actually had a project named `jboss` without any facets, just to have the JBoss files visible from the eclipse project browser. This project was closed.

After I opened it, the server started fine again.

I am still clueless about how the reference to the `jboss-modules.jar` from a project got into the launch config classpath and why it resisted removing attempts.

Answer (score 2):

`modules.jar` is required to run **JBOSS 7.1 Runtime**, which is missing.

1. Go to `Window > Preferences > Server > Runtime Environment > Default Classpath`.
   If you don't see any classpath in the right side menu,you can tweek the classpath setting by-

   1. Change server to JBOSS 7.0 Runtime.
   2. Again Change server to JBOSS 7.1 Runtime.

Delete and Add Server Again,

while *Add new server*,

1. Please Check the 2nd and 3rd checkboxes
   -"Listen on all Interfaces to allow remote web connections"
   -"Expose your management port as server's hostname"

now everything will run fine.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a late response but in case anyone needs a solution to this issue.

If you go to Window > Preferences > Servers > Runtime Environments > Default Classpath

You will see that the 'JBoss 7.0 Runtime' does not have 'modules../-[**/*.jar]' dependency, which is where the jboss-modules.jar lives. After selecting the 'JBoss 7.0 Runtime' rather than the JBoss 7.1 Runtime, the error relating to the jboss-modules.jar went away, and the server starts without error.

My application also started without error. I am using JBoss 7.1.1.